# SMD Fuse - DC voltage rating higher than AC?

Tags: fuses

I would like to use the Bel Fuse C2Q (https://belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-cp-c2q-series.pdf) for a new PCB design. It is conveniently packed in a 0603 instead of the larger C1Q which comes in a 1206 package.

However, while I always thought that DC voltage rating for fuses was lower than AC, this particular fuse features a voltage rating of 32V AC and 63V DC. How is that possible? It does not make much sense to me and it makes me concerned that I should understand it better before I use it in my design...

The circuit runs some motors out of a 24V lithium-ion battery, so I am not expecting any proper AC, but maybe some spikes here and there. While the 63V DC is totally fine, I don't like that 32V AC very much. Any advice?

Comment: Compare Vpp of AC rms to DC. Unless specified assume rms.

Comment: The value is the agency approval sought by the manufacturer. Maybe they decided that some fuses are more applicable to AC and tested then at only 32 volts whereas some fuses were tested also at 63 volts DC. Maybe they ran out of budget for doing a full AC/DC equivalent test.